# Disable <select> when checkbox enabled

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to use javascript to set the attribute disabled="disabled" to the  with id age 2 when the checkbox with id "exactage" is enabled. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. A happy coder :)

```
 <select id="age">
        <option value="18"><18</option>
    </select>

    <select id="age2">
        <option value="18"><18</option>
    </select>

   <input type="checkbox" id="exactage"/> Require exact age
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by enabled you mean checked

```
if(document.getElementById('exactage').checked)
    document.getElementById('age2').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

If by enabled you actually mean enabled, you can do this:

```
if(document.getElementById('exactage').getAttribute('disabled') !== null)
    document.getElementById('age2').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: @user1014805 you need to place the javascript code after the checkboxes markup html. If the js is placed before it, the checkboxes won't yet exist in the DOM when the js gets executed.

Comment: @user1014805 Well your `exactage` checkbox doesn't start out checked so you won't see anything. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AVFeQ/), it works fine.

Comment: @user1014805 You need to create an event for that. Perhaps an `onchange` event.

Comment: sorry, really n00by, how do i do that?

Answer (score 3):

Note that I had a momentary blind-spot when I wrote this answer: I could've sworn that I saw a [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) tag. Sigh. My mistake, it's not worth revising this answer, now, since other functional plain JS answers are posted, that I can't improve upon.

I will, however, change this to community wiki, and leave it for the moment as further information.

---

The following should work for you, ***if*** you're using jQuery (see my above addenda, regarding blind-spots):

```
$('#exactage').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#age2').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#age2').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
```

On the `change` event of the `#exactage` checkbox the `if` checks whether `$(this)` is, or is not, `:checked`. If it *is* then it sets the `disabled` property of the `#age2` element, otherwise it removes/unsets the `disabled` property.

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Comment: I don't see a jQuery tag on this.

Comment: Sigh, I could've sworn I saw a [tag:jquery] tag... =/

Comment: <script>
$('#exactage').change(
    function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')){
            $('#age2').prop('disabled',true);
        }
        else {
            $('#age2').prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });
</script>

 <form>
 
 <select id="age">
  <option value="18"><18</option>
 </select>
 
 to
 
 <select id="age2">
  <option value="18"><18</option>
 </select>
 
 <br/>
 
 <input type="checkbox" id="exactage" require="false"> Require exact age
 
 </form>

Answer (score 0):

You can try onclick or onselect (I think there is something like that) attribute to call a method 
In the method try

```
document.getElementById('age2').setEnabled(false)
```

or

```
    document.getElementById('age2').disabled=disabled
```

Something along that line.. I can't remember :(

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following.

```
if(document.getElementById('exactage').checked)
{
    document.getElementById('age2').disabled=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need these

```
function changeState(id, state)
{
    if(state == 0)
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = true;
    else
        document.getElementById(id).disabled = false;
}

function toggleFields(id, state)
{
    var e=document.getElementById(id);
    if(!e)return true;
    if(state == 1)
    {
        e.style.display=""
    }
    else
    {
        e.style.display="none";
    }
    return true;
}
```

Followed by these

```
function checkBoxState(check_box_id, field_id, flag)
{
    if(document.getElementById(check_box_id).checked)
    {
        if(flag == 1)
            toggleFields(field_id, 1);
        else if(flag == 0)
            changeState(field_id, 1);
        document.getElementById(check_box_id).value = 1;
    } else {
        if(flag == 1)
            toggleFields(field_id, 0);
        else if(flag == 0)
            changeState(field_id, 0);
        document.getElementById(check_box_id).value = 0;
    }
}

function reversedCheckBoxState(check_box_id, field_id, flag)
{
    if(document.getElementById(check_box_id).checked)
    {
        if(flag == 1)
            toggleFields(field_id, 0);
        else
            changeState(field_id, 0);
        document.getElementById(check_box_id).value = 1;
    } else {
        if(flag == 1)
            toggleFields(field_id, 1);
        else
            changeState(field_id, 1);
        document.getElementById(check_box_id).value = 0;
    }
}
```

And now all you will have to do is to run reversedCheckBoxState("exactage", "age2" 0)
Or you can run reversedCheckBoxState("exactage", "age2" 1)

Enjoy!